# Entity Refresh - The refresh attempt has failed because an unexpected entity was returned by the data source

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, refresh

when I run a query in EF, the DbContext in it automatically caches the data that it retrieves from the database using query. In some cases it is helpful but I need to to hit database and get in which data changes outside the context.
So I did some researches and I saw I need to refresh my dbcontext. I tried it bu it gives following error. How to fix this error?

> The refresh attempt has failed because an unexpected entity was
> returned by the data source.

```
using (var ctx = new MyDbContext()){
..
var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext;
var refreshEntities = ctx.ChangeTracker.Entries().Select(x => x.Entity).ToList();
objContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, refreshEntities);
..
}
```

Context;

```
 public MyDbContext() : base(OraConnection(), true) { }
             public DbSet<Books> Book{ get; set; }
             public DbSet<Libraries> Library{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today. There was a trailing whitespace character in one of the fields in my dataset. That field also happened to be part of the EF Key. The trailing space was unexpected so I removed it in my dataset and the error went away.

I hope that your issue is just as straightforward.